# notepad++ drop down suggestions not showing

Tags: notepad++

When I type in an HTML tag into Notepad++ then available options should show in a drop down menu like shown in the picture below, however, there is no drop down menu showing on my computer:

http://i.grab.la/07305-5d310c35-4bc3-4fb1-8f00-c11dbd0fc8a6.png

Who knows how to turn this on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an english version of Npp, but I think it is:

```
Settings > Preferences > Autocomplete > then check what is in the right panel
```

Comment: Thanks Toto. I checked everything but still the same issue :(

See http://grabilla.com/0730a-fedbb918-fa21-46c1-9e8d-b5d1e20d7383.html

Comment: is it maybe a separate plugin that I need to install?

Comment: @Jack2345: No needs for plugin, it should work, it works for me, version 7.2.2